# Compiling sass with SassyStudio and Compass and multiple areas

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Iam trying SassyStudio für Visual Studio to compile the SASS in our project - but there area some issues.

The project is structured like this:

```
Solution
- Project 1
-- Areas
--- Area 1
---- Styles
----- style.scss
------ style.css
--- Area 2
---- Styles
----- style.scss
------ style.css
-- Styles
--- globalstyle.scss
---- glogalstyle.css
```

As you can see the scss files are scattered all around the project. The css Files should be compiled beside the scss files. Since there are compass references within the scss files there are dependencies to compass.

Mindscape Web Workbench is not designed to work like this.

I installed Ruby + gem sass + gem compass and

```
sass --watch C:/compasstest:C:/compasstest --compass
```

works well. But I dont like to start a batch everytime I start developing.

So I found SassyStudio an it pretty looks like what I need. But there are some issues with the compass references. In the options I entered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Ruby193\bin" to Ruby Install Path and "C:\compass" to the Include Paths property. The Compass Folder contains for example the "compass/css3" structure from github.

```
12:00:52.447 : Failed to compile css.
[SassCompileException]c:\compass/compass/css3/shared:1: error: file to import not found or unreadable: "compass/support"

at NSass.SassCompiler.CompileFile(String inputPath, OutputStyle outputStyle, Boolean sourceComments, IEnumerable`1 additionalIncludePaths)
at SassyStudio.Integration.LibSass.NSassDocumentCompiler.Compile(FileInfo source, FileInfo output)
at SassyStudio.Editor.GenerateCssOnSave.GenerateCss(DateTime time, String path)

12:00:52.447 : Compile complete.
```

- What exactly is Ruby Install Path for?
- Do I need the config.rb even if I dont want so specifiy specifiy sass and css folder?
- How can I tell SassyStudio to find the file compass/support (It already found compass/shared as we can see)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the `sass --compass` is new to me, so I don't know if I can comment on that.

Here is what you want to do.

First, change your ruby path to this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ruby193` as you don't need the bin directory in there (and not sure if it would cause issue or not).

Next, for me to detect that you are using compass (vs sass gem), I look for the config.rb file, and I believe that compass requires this to work as well, but not exactly sure on that. For me though, I definitely need it.

Now, what happens when you save a file is that I go looking for that `config.rb` from the current directory upward, so I believe that you can achieve what you are wanting to do through the use of multiple `compass.rb` files. So, that means if you put one in `Area 1`, one in `Area 2`, and one in `Styles`, I think it will work (but I've never tried).

I'm a bit unfamiliar with the syntax of compass.rb but I'm sure you will be able to figure out something that works there. That file may need to go into the Styles folder instead of root folders, I don't remember for sure (I think styles is perhaps configured in `config.rb`).

Let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: Thank you @Darren Kopp

First I included the bin directory because I got an exception telling me that ""ruby.exe"" could not be found. Yesterday I updated to the latest version of SassyStudio and now it works without the bin directory.

I tried to place a config.rb in every single directory and it seems to work pretty well. I set css_dir = "/" and sass_dir = "/".

It would be great if newly generated css files could be added to the project - may DependentUpon.

Comment: @philipoo yeah, I want to add that too, I'll just need to add a config.rb parser so I know where the files are going to and if they are in the same directory then I can nest them or add them to the project if not.

Comment: Update: As I see its not nessesary to place an config.rb in every single subdirectory. I place one at root and the compiled css files are still placed beside the scss files in the subdirectories.